# Unable to print the data retrieved from regex(strictly only this) module in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Here iam using 're' module in python to crawl a web page and there are 4 iterations and after each iteration it is returning with empty array like this [''] but the output should be the stock price of desired stock symbol.There is no error in regex variable as it is printing correctly.The source code is included below.

```
import urllib
import re

symbolslist = ["appl","spy","goog","nflx"]

i=0
while i<len(symbolslist):
        url ="http://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" +symbolslist[i] +"&ql=1"
        htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
        htmltext = htmlfile.read()
        regex ='<span id="yfs_l84_'+symbolslist[i] +'">(.+?)</span>'
        pattern = re.compile(regex)
        print regex
        price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
        print "price of ",symbolslist[i],"is",price
        i+=1
```

And in the output there is no syntax or indentation error and output looks like this

```
<span id="yfs_l84_appl">(.+?)</span>
price of  appl is []
<span id="yfs_l84_spy">(.+?)</span>
price of  spy is []
<span id="yfs_l84_goog">(.+?)</span>
price of  goog is []
<span id="yfs_l84_nflx">(.+?)</span>
price of  nflx is []
```

In the array the value of the stock is not printing

Web Page crawled is https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=NFLX&ql=0

Comment: Use an html parser like BeautifulSoup to parse html!

Comment: Print the html text variable before running regex on it. I would not be surprised, if the actual stock price is updated using AJAX and it is not in the HTML you receive

Comment: @jpou the same program is working for a single stock symbol and is failing if we run a array on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative approach, you might find it easier to use the [`yahoo_finance`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) library as follows:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share

for symbol in ["appl", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]:
    yahoo = Share(symbol)
    print 'Price of {} is {}'.format(symbol, yahoo.get_price())
```

Giving you the following output:

```
Price of appl is 96.11
Price of spy is 186.63
Price of goog is 682.40
Price of nflx is 87.40
```

It is never a wise move to try and parse HTML data using regular expressions.

---

Another approach would be to extract the information first using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

for symbol in ["appl", "spy", "goog", "nflx"]:
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={}'.format(symbol)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    data = soup.find('span', attrs= {'id' : re.compile(r'yfs_.*?_{}'.format(symbol.lower()))})
    print 'Price of {} is {}'.format(symbol, data.text)
```

Comment: But my approach is to use regex module only for now

Comment: @SaiKiranUppu: [***N̵̻̹̪͉͔͍̞̲̹͑͛́̆̈́̆̈͌͗͊ͅḘ̣̪̣̺͓̟͛̅́̇͗̂͑͋̒͛ͅV̵̢̢̫͇͍̩̳͖̼̌̑̒͋͠E̷̘̱̦͓̝̝̫͎̼͛͗͋̉͛̾̚͟Ṙ̘͕̭̲̠͛͌̐̀͞ U̸̢̲̭̜͈̰̇́̽̾͗̉̕͝ͅS͙̥̙͖̏̆́͗̀̉͜͞E̛̺̜̪̠͕̅̏̏͑̆̄̕̕̕ Ŗ̥̼̘̯͉̻̻̏̓͒́͛̔͜͡Ȩ̵̦̙̰̼̘̰̲͎͗͗͛̉͐̎̕͡G̴̡͔͓͚̺̗̟̟͈̎͛͂̽̄ͅÈ̷̡͈͎̣̫̟̊͋̇́̕X̨̨̝̣̋̀͆̽̅̽̄͟ Ṗ̛̳͈͚̞̤̹̭̦̣̽̀̈Ą̦̫͎̪̠͉̫͋̐̉̏͌̓̔̓̉Ŗ̼̮̥͕͎͈̦̔̌͑̊̿S̸̢̮̳̱̗̗͖̋̿̑̊̇̄̀E̴̙̱̳͉̍̽͗̆̐̆͢͟͝͝ H̦̝͕͔̙̙̳͍̻̋̑̈̇̐̾̀͝͡͠ͅŢ̵̧͎̭̣̪͎̞̳̄̀͒̒̋̚͝M̸̢̻̱̖͈͕͊̌͌̋̚͟L̷͕̣̻̗̞̐̈́̓̐̀̈́̾͜͜͠͝***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Click on the link, it will take you to the website where you can download and install the library.